# Triggering a second PC via ehternet

Tags: python-2.7, psychopy

I'm trying to use Psychopy to trigger a second machine's data collection.  I could use an I/O card, but I wondered how difficult it would be to use the NICs in Ad-Hoc mode?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We are currently communicating with an eye link 2 running our experiment on one machine and the eye link software on another. In some tests of the mirametrix eye tracker we also used some variations of virtual and real machines talking to one another (as an aside, we never quite got the performance from the mirametrix that we needed).

We mention some of the tools we used here: https://brittlab.uwaterloo.ca/research-tips/

If you have a network card in each machine you could just connect them with an ethernet cable and set up tcp/ip to let the programs on the two machines talk to each other. If one machine needs to also talk to the outside world you could add a second network card (or if a laptop just buy a cheap usb wireless).

With more specifics about what you are trying to achieve others may be able to give you more specific feedback.